# How to send commands to an already open command window

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, command-prompt

I need to be able to send commands to an already open command window. I run a bat file using python which opens a command window and it stays running, I then need to be able to send a command to that same command window, using python.

Code snippet:

```
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\TheRi\\Desktop\\mine\\Minecraft")
file = os.startfile("C:\\Users\\TheRi\\Desktop\\mine\\Minecraft\\Start.bat")
```

I change the directory to where the bat file is and i run it using os.startfile, opening the bat file is really easy. But I can't figure out a way to send a command to it. I need to run "stop" to the command window, which should save everything and then close the window. I've tried using the subprocess module but that didn't work for me and I can't find anything else similar which might allow me to do this.

I'm using windows 10 and python 3.6.8

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well if its a batch file you should be able to right click the actual file, click *edit*, and add commands directly to it? Its just a text file with a .bat extension. Also I believe the command is `exit` not `stop`

Sorry in advance if I misunderstood your question, or if you don't want to edit the file for some reason.

Comment: I need the command to run when the user needs it to run, not just straight after the command. The bat file launches a minecraft server and "stop" is for that process. So whenever the user wants to kill the server I need "stop" to send to the terminal. Thank's for your input though, I probably should have been more specific.

Comment: You could make a for loop in the batch file that loops continuously until the contents of a text file change, then it runs stop. I believe that changing the contents of text files is pretty easy, at least with java, idk about python...